# In C#, won't drag enter, drag drop and drag leave get triggered when a control is dragged and dropped over other?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

In C#, when I drop a file on panel, drag events are triggered automatically. But if I drag a control like Button on another control like Button, no drag event gets triggered. Do we need to use mouse down and mouse down for this?

Comment: Show us the code with the button drag events that don't fire

Comment: Did you enable it in the properties??

Comment: Yes I did enable properties. I don't have code snippet because I have taken different approach and completed. But my question is direct - will drag events get fired when a user do drag and drop a button on another button?